# Mysite Migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 without a Content DB migration

Tags: 2007, administration, my-site, migration

We have 3000 and add users in our SharePoint 2007 farm and they do have their Mysites, Now we want to migrate only 200 users mysites (including the contents) to SharePoint 2010 farm.

Want to perform this without doing a Content DB migration.

What would be the best approach to follow, please help me with the steps as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, why are you against content db migration?

Since it's only 200 users, I would do a backup of those 200 mysites.  Then delete those mysites, then create a new db (take all others offline) and restore the 200 mysites to that new db.  Then you can do the content db migration of just those 200 mysites.

UPDATE:

So, I would create the new 200 mysites using the default site definition in SP 2010, and then write a console app or something that uses webservices to copy the content.

Comment: We have deployed few WSPs for the Mysite webapplication in SharePoint 2007 farm and we do not want to have those WSPs installed on SharePoint 2010 farm.

If we migrate the Content DB, we have to deploy the same WSPs in SharePoint 2010 farm which we do not want to do as mentioned above.

Our Aim is we want to migrate the Mysites with its content (documents, list items...) to our new SharePoint 2010 farm without deploying the older solution packages exists in SharePoint 2007 farm.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  I'll revise my answer.

Comment: If it is possible, let me know how to migrate the content using the console app or webservices?

Comment: Ok, i would get all of the list xml schemas and if they don't exist, create them in the new site based on the schema.  I would then create the views.  I would then get the item xml for each item and create it in the new list.  If the item also happens to be a file, use the spitem.file.openbinary to get the byte array and then create that same file in the new site.  Do the same thing for attachements and I think that's about it.